# How to make Angular-Google-Map Full screen by default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

When the Google map is loaded, there is an option like the one shown below to make it fullscreen:
[As shown in this image, there is a button to click, which will make the map full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jpCF.png)

[image]

However, I want my map to open complete fullscreen by default (basically what happens if the button in the image above is clicked).

What configuration can be used for this? I

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Browsers require a click from the user to put an application fullscreen, on purpose (for some reason, probably some security measure of some sort). I believe it can't be done programmatically, you need a user click.